# Python tkinter main window closes all other windows too, why?

Tags: python, tkinter

I made a gui programm with Tkinter. In the program are several buttons which open new main tkinter windows but when i click on the 'x' of one of these windows all the other ones close too although they are different windows. Only the Buttons, which cause the new tkinter main windows, are in the same main window.

please help :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how tkinter is designed to work. When you destroy a window, all of its children are destroyed. Since everything is a child of the root window or one of its children, when you destroy the root window all other widgets are destroyed along with it.